# Resuming multiple downloads in Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, file-system, file-transfer, downloading

Many sites give all their files the same name. When downloading multiple files like this, Chrome helpfully adds a (1), (2), etc. to the filename. However, if something interrupts the download, such as a full memory or a connection reset, I find that Chrome often refuses to resume the download, on the grounds that "file already exists." Typically these are incomplete files and are useless if the download can not be resumed.

The problem here is not that Chrome is unable to resume the download per se. If you go to downloads you get the option of resuming. The problem is that Chrome refuses to resume a download if a file of that name exists, where 8f it were a new file it would just be renumbered.

Is there any way to get Chrome to finish the downloads in these circumstances?

Comment: May be a download manager app that takes over the download from Chrome would better suite your needs?

Comment: Downloading abilities of mainstream browsers are not flexible (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc). Your best bet is to rely on a download manager app to manage your downloads including mass resuming. Download resume also depend upon whether the server allows that or not.